# SQL Server 2012 Express with Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

Everywhere I search for SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services, I ended up with this link, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579, and every time I install it, I do not see where I can add reporting services as a feature.

Is there another installation file that includes Reporting Services, or do I actually have it now but cannot tell it's installed? I went to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services already and do not see it listed, which tells me that it's not installed?

**Update**: I've followed Kin's instructions, but just cannot advance further.  Here's where I am now. In Reporting Services Configuration Manager, the Connect button is grayed out, and when I click on Find, I get error message of "Unable to connect to the Reporting Services..." See below.
[image]

When I go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I do not see Reporting Services as a service listed to start of stop. See below.
[image]

So, in my mind, perhaps I don't have the Reporting Services installed, so I try to install the features, but there's no Reporting Services listed as an available feature to add. See below. I know I downloaded the .exe file that includes everything available to download, including the Reporting Services. What should my next steps be to troubleshoot further? I'm tempted to uninstall and reinstall, but I'm not confident that I can uninstall properly. There seems to be so many files related to SQL Server 2012, and I'm not sure how that would affect Visual Studio I currently have installed. By the way, I'm on a local desktop installation with Windows 7.
[image]

Comment: I think you just "add to existing" and select reporting services. Hopefully relevant screenshots: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/media/users/koenverbeeck/SP2013DemoEnv/Part9/InstallSSRS_01.png?mtime=1370459857 http://blogs.lessthandot.com/media/users/koenverbeeck/SP2013DemoEnv/Part9/InstallSSRS_02.png?mtime=1370459858

Comment: Which file you are using to install ? `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` - Contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search, `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` contains ONLY Database Engine, No Tools or reporting service.

Comment: I installed SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe.  Do you mind telling me where you downloaded SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe?  The only one I was able to find was for 2008 version.

Comment: @LatexPerson I have updated my answer.

Comment: @LatexPerson What `.exe` are you using for installation ?

Comment: @Kin, I use the one provided by you.  I selected all the features available, including Reporting Services.

Comment: @LatexPerson You are not even connected to the instance. Refer to [SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Tool](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1453/sql-server-reporting-services-configuration-tool/). This will help you out.

Comment: It looks like the link moved to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Answer (score 9):

Following up on my comment, you have to select `ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` for installation.

[image]

[Download link.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Then run the installation package and follow instruction until you get feature selection page.

[image]

Follow rest of the steps and complete the installation.

**Now Verify the RS installation :**

Note: You must be logged in as a member of the local administrators group on the computer where SQL Server 2012 Express is installed.

1. Navigate to Start  -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager.
2. In the RS Configuration Connection dialog, make sure that your local report server instance (for example SQLExpess) is selected and click Connect.

   [image]
3. In the RS Configuration Manager left pane, select Web Service 
   URL.

   [image]
4. Make sure that the Virtual Directory parameter is set to ‘ReportServer_’ (‘ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS’ for the SQLEXPRESS instance), and that the TCP Port is set to 80. Click Apply.
5. In the Reporting Services Configuration Manager left pane, select Database. 
   [image]
6. On this page, ensure that the SQL Server Name and Database Name fields contain correct values. If not, click the Change Database button and complete the Report Server Database Configuration wizard.
7. In the Reporting Services Configuration Manager left pane, select Report Manager URL.
8. On this page, ensure that the Virtual Directory parameter is set correctly, and that the URL is valid.
9. Click Exit to close the RS Configuration Manager.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide screenshots and direction. I followed it until I got to the add features section. When I reached the Feature Selection, I only have three features I can add, none of them is the Reporting Services you highlighted.I guess I already have it installed.  When I launched Reporting Services Configuration Manager as Administrator, by right click and Run as administrator, I'm not sure if it's the same as you indicated, but I get the "Unable to connect the Report Server.."error message.How do you attach image like you have?It would have been easier to reference.

Comment: @LatexPerson Add it to original Question. Refer [here on how to add/attach image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: you are the man!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem of Microsoft. When I first installed the SQL 2012 Express advance I still have difficult connecting the report service. after started Reporting Services Configuration Manager, there is no database been set to by default used by the report service although the databases are already there. after you choose new database(or from remote) or just select the SSRS database which existed. then you can go through all the settings followed. then everything should be fine. hope this would help.